# Moment generating function of a function

Tags: probability

I need to find MGF of $Z = \mu + \frac{1}{\lambda}X$ ($\mu, \lambda$ are constants). How do I do that?

**UPDATE**

If it helps:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp{ \{ -\frac{x^2}{2} \} }$$

So ...

$$M_X(t) = te^{t^2/2}$$

Comment: Are you asking how to go from the moment generating function of $X$ to that of $Z$?

Comment: If I can do that its fine too. Updated the question with more info

Comment: I believe you have misstated the moment generating function for a unit normal random variable, c.f. [The Moment Generating Function of the Normal Distribution](http://www.le.ac.uk/users/dsgp1/COURSES/MATHSTAT/6normgf.pdf) which gives $M_X(t) = e^{\frac{1}{2}t^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [general rule](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/170) is this:

$$ M_Z(t) = E[e^{tZ}] = E[e^{t(\mu + \frac{1}{\lambda})X}]
 = e^{t\mu} E[e^{(t \frac{1}{\lambda})X}] $$

$$ M_Z(t) = e^{t\mu} M_X(t \frac{1}{\lambda}) $$

So if you know the moment generating function of $X$, you have the moment generating function of $Z$.  In any event the "additional information" in the Question now specifies that $X$ is a normally distributed random variable, so [its moment generating function is well-known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moment_and_cumulant_generating_functions).

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of facts that are good exercises to prove, and should get you what you need.

Given any constants $\alpha,\beta$ and any random variable $X,$ we have:

- $M_{\alpha+X}(t)=e^{\alpha t}M_X(t)$
- $M_{\beta X}(t)=M_X(\beta t)$

It's worth noting, though (as hardmath points out in the comments above), that if your density function is as written, then you should have $$M_X(t)=e^{\frac12t^2}.$$